# How to pass 2 parameters in a method in WCF Service using Objective c?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, wcf, soap

My Parameters are

```
Request1 = <Request> <name>2</name> <pwd>1</pwd> </Request>

Request2 = value1
```

My Code is

```
-(void)webRequestCommnunication
{
//Web Service Call
 NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"> <soap:Body><Method1 xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><Request1><Request> <name>2</name> <pwd>1</pwd> </Request></Request1><Request2>value1</Request2></Method1></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localIPaddress/servicename1/servicename2/Method1.svc"];

theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];

[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/service1/Method1" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Soapaction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
webData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
if(theConnection)
{

    NSLog(@"Connected....");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}
}
```

I want to pass Request1, Request2 inside Method1,but it throws exception as The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'Method1'. End element 'Request1' from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/' expected. Found element 'Request' from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/'. Line 1, position 276..

Can anyone suggest what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Finally Got solution!

While sending Request1 parameter  the <,> symbol is not parsed in Soap Format,only the parent tag  the symbol is validated and the modified code is

```
-(void)webRequestCommnunication
{
//Web Service Call
 NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                     @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"> <soap:Body><Method1 xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><Request1><Request1>&lt;Request&gt;&lt;name&gt;2&lt;/name&gt;&lt;pwd&gt;1&lt;/pwd&gt;&lt;/Request&gt;</Request1><Request2>value1</Request2></Method1></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localIPaddress/servicename1/servicename2/Method1.svc"];

theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


 NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];

[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/service1/Method1" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Soapaction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
webData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
if(theConnection)
{

   NSLog(@"Connected....");
}
else
{
  NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}
}
```